# Responsive fullscreen youtube video with no black bars?

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

I have a fullscreen youtube video embedded on my website.

[image]

It looks good when the size of the browser is proportional to the video’s width and height. However, when I resize the browser to a different proportion, I get black bars around the video.

[image]

What I want is to have the video fill the whole window at all times, but without any stretching. I want the “excess” to hide when the browser size is not proportional to the video.

What I am trying to achieve is something you can see in the background of these two websites: http://ginlane.com/ and http://www.variousways.com/.

Is it possible to do this with a youtube video?

Answer (score 14):

This is pretty old but people may still need help here. I needed this too so have created a Pen of my solution which should help - http://codepen.io/MikeMooreDev/pen/QEEPMv

The example shows two versions of the same video, one as standard and the second cropped and centrally aligned to fit the size of the full parent element without showing the hideous black bars.

You need to use some javascript to calculate a new width for the video but it's really easy if you know the aspect ratio.

HTML

```
<div id="videoWithNoJs" class="videoWrapper">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ja8pA2B0RR4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS - The height and width o the videoWrapper can be anything, they can be percentages if you so wish

```
.videoWrapper {
  height:600px;
  width:600px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // - 1.78 is the aspect ratio of the video
    // - This will work if your video is 1920 x 1080
    // - To find this value divide the video's native width by the height eg 1920/1080 = 1.78
    var aspectRatio = 1.78;

    var video = $('#videoWithJs iframe');
    var videoHeight = video.outerHeight();
    var newWidth = videoHeight*aspectRatio;
    var halfNewWidth = newWidth/2;

    video.css({"width":newWidth+"px","left":"50%","margin-left":"-"+halfNewWidth+"px"});

});
```

This can also be triggered on resize to ensure it remains responsive. The easiest (probably not most efficient) way to do this is with the following.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {

    // Same code as on load        
    var aspectRatio = 1.78;
    var video = $('#videoWithJs iframe');
    var videoHeight = video.outerHeight();
    var newWidth = videoHeight*aspectRatio;
    var halfNewWidth = newWidth/2;

    video.css({"width":newWidth+"px","left":"50%","margin-left":"-"+halfNewWidth+"px"});

});
```

Answer (score 13):

To simulate the same effect, the important thing is to maintain aspect ratio which is 16:9.

HTML

```
<div class="banner-video">    
        <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXlJXRXJhow?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=XXlJXRXJhow" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
iframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc((100vw*9) /16);
}
```

This will remove black bars.

Now we can set the outer container to 100% width and 100% height and hide the overflow.

```
.banner-video{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now the above code will work until viewport aspect ratio is greater than 16/9. So we have to add media query based on aspect ratio.

```
 @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .banner-video{
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    iframe{
      width: calc((100vh*16)/9);
      height: 100vh;
      }
  }
```

After this youtube video will maintain full viewport size at all condition and hide the extra part of a video.
Other then opera it's supported in all the browser.

Comment: This one worked for me, thanks! Very detailed answer, awesome job. Although one thing, for me I had to make the iframe positioned as absolute, left 50%, top 50%, and translate it -50%, -50%

Answer (score 11):

Create a container div around the iframe code and give it a class eg:

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe.......></iframe></div>
```

Add in the CSS:

```
.video-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This [coolestguidesontheplanet.com](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/youtube/) is the Source URL of this answer.

Comment: This worked for me, only thing i had to remove was the padding-top

Comment: I still had the black bars until I set the padding-top: 0; then it worked.

Comment: after applying this black bar gone. but another new problem appears. which is max-height: 100vh is not working. I dont want to cross the margin of 100vh. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking just for CSS (no JS).

Videos with 16:9 ratio such as 1920x1080 or 1280x720...

Here is my code (It's working in my case):

```
.video {
    position: relative;
    height: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /*16:9*/
    padding-top: 0; /* Use ZERO, not 25px or 30px and so on */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: but I want to keep the max-height: 100vh.
is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this because the answers above are for when you have the black bars at the top and at the bottom. What if you have the bars on the sides (left and right). This script will take care of the two scenario.

```
    var vidRatio = vidWidth/vidHeight;
var wrapperHeight = $('#videoIFrameContainer').height();
var wrapperWidth = $('#videoIFrameContainer').width();
var wrapperRatio = wrapperWidth / wrapperHeight;
if(wrapperRatio < vidRatio){
    var newWidth  = wrapperWidth  * (vidRatio/wrapperRatio);
    $('#videoIFrame').css({'min-height':wrapperHeight+'px', 'min-width':newWidth+'px', 'position':'absolute', 'left':'50%','margin-left':'-'+(newWidth/2)+'px'});

}
else{
    var newHeight  = wrapperHeight   * (wrapperRatio / vidRatio);
    $('#videoIFrame').css({'min-height':newHeight+'px', 'min-width':wrapperWidth+'px', 'position':'absolute', 'top':'50%','margin-top':'-'+(newHeight/2)+'px'});

}
```

Comment: Great solution :) Thanks. Btw. it does not center video correctly in the middle of wrapper when both width and height of wrapper are smaller than width and height of video.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out but here's a simple CSS solution that works for me using Flexbox. Basically, put the  video in a container with position absolute and width and height 100% and the make it display:flex and center the content!

https://medium.com/@rishabhaggarwal2/tutorial-how-to-do-full-screen-youtube-video-embeds-without-any-black-bars-faa778db499c

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this doesn't seem to be working.... Unless I am missing something: 
http://codepen.io/Archie22is/pen/EWWoEM

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // - 1.78 is the aspect ratio of the video
    // - This will work if your video is 1920 x 1080
    // - To find this value divide the video's native width by the height eg 1920/1080 = 1.78
    var aspectRatio = 1.78;

    var video = $('#videoWithJs iframe');
    var videoHeight = video.outerHeight();
    var newWidth = videoHeight*aspectRatio;
    var halfNewWidth = newWidth/2;

    video.css({"width":newWidth+"px","left":"50%","margin-left":"-"+halfNewWidth+"px"});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this below:-

```
<iframe class="" style="background:url(ImageName.jpg) center; background-size: 100% 140%; " allowfullscreen="" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualy filling the screen responsively with minimal possible scaling requires a bit of javascript. The trick is to calculate the scaling factor in both width and height and scale both width and height in one of those factors, depending on the aspect of the window.

```
const vp = document.getElementById("videoElement"),
      box = vp.getBoundingClientRect(),
      vidw = 640,
      vidh = 360;

const resize = () => {
    const w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        iw = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        ih = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight,
        wf = iw / vidw,
        hf = ih / vidh;

    let nw, nh, dx, dy;
    if (wf >= hf) {
        nw = iw;
        nh = vidh * wf;
        dx = 0;
        dy = -0.5 * (vidh * wf - ih);
    } else {
        nw = vidw * hf;
        nh = ih;
        dx = -0.5 * (vidw * hf - iw);
        dy = 0;
    }

    vp.style.width = `${nw}px`;
    vp.style.height = `${nh}px`;
    vp.style.transform = `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px)`;
};
```

[Here's a full example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/josfabre/pen/gOdBwZe)