# Inserting a video over an image with css and html

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a graphic on my website, http://176.32.230.43/testdigitalmarketingmentor.co.uk/ where a video is played from within a picture of a laptop (so it looks like the video is playing on the laptop screen). I also want this to be mobile responsive (i.e. rescale depending on screen size). You can scroll down to "Showreel" to see what I have managed so far with the following css and html... Any help/advice/guidance would be appreciated!

```css
#laptop-panel {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        height: 625px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #laptop-panel-tv {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url('http://176.32.230.43/testdigitalmarketingmentor.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/laptop-1000x728-trans.png') no-repeat center;
    z-index: 10;
    }

    #laptop-panel-content-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 444px;
        z-index: 12;

    .embed-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
 
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="laptop-panel">
    <div id="laptop-panel-tv"></div>
    <div id="laptop-panel-content-overlay">
    <div id="laptop-panel-content">
        <div class="embed-container">
        <div style="width: 683px; " class="wp-video">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>    <script>document.createElement('video');</script><![endif]-->

   <div class="video-container">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BhEWkcyXYwg?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div></div></div>            
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is what it looks like...]

Comment: Whats the problem with this?

Comment: The video isn't appearing on the website, it's just a black box with the play button etc, but it doesn't do anything when clicked.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the MIME type that the player is processing. Why not just embed the youtube player with a default html5 attribute? https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: I could do, how would I implement this please?

Comment: Just posted a solution for you. Hope it helps. Please mark it as the answer if it does. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be okay using something like this? It also helps to have more views on Youtube.

```css
    #laptop-panel {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 67.5%;
        height: 0;
    }
    #laptop-panel iframe {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url(http://176.32.230.43/testdigitalmarketingmentor.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/laptop-1000x728-trans.png) center center no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        padding: 11.7% 17.9% 15.4%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="laptop-panel">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BhEWkcyXYwg?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to change anything... I'm still just getting a black box with the play icons but it's not doing anything when clicked. I've tried clearing my cache but no difference... Any ideas?

Comment: I made a pen for you. Can you check this out? http://codepen.io/IsabelInc/pen/wWPQxw

Comment: This works great, any idea how to make it mobile responsive though? Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Adding a width:100% should do the trick. Here are some links with examples for responsive videos https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/youtube/ Hope this answers your question. Good luck

Comment: This works for the video, but how can I use it so the laptop border also resizes? At the moment, on mobile, the video plays nicely but there are black bars to the top and bottom, covering the laptop image.

Comment: The black bars appear because of aspect ratio issues. Could you show a screenshot of what it looks like with the bars?

Comment: Looks like I found a solution on stack here's  the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617154/responsive-fullscreen-youtube-video-with-no-black-bars

Comment: Any luck with the link?

Comment: I've updated my first post with the code I'm currently using, from the links you provided. It seems to be making the video really small (even on desktop). Also I need to make the laptop image responsive too (so they both re-size together).

Comment: Check this out  http://codepen.io/IsabelInc/pen/zBpAOp  . There is a point when you need to readjust the padding on really small screens. All you need to do is add some media queries to adjust the padding slightly on the mobile depending on when the padding is not sufficient. Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Not really sure how to implement this? Should it replace something already in my css or be added to it? Not sure what it's supposed to be doing!!

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can just replace all your other code (html and css) with this code. Hope this answers your question. If it does don't forget to mark this as the answer. Cheers