# disabling blackbars on youtube embed iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I embed a video from youtube to my web page I want it to be stretch 100% on the screen with no blackbars. Although I give it a width of 100%, it still has some blackbars on the sides of the video. How can I get rid of it?

Screenshot:[image: Screenshot] 
snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/o3rp6an9/1/

```
<div id="video">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zWAiQJvwb8Q?autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&playlist=zWAiQJvwb8Q&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>

#video {
    height:100%;
    width:100% !important;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

There's another question about this but it basically didn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive fullscreen youtube video with no black bars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617154/responsive-fullscreen-youtube-video-with-no-black-bars)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to absolutely position the video within a wrapper that sets vertical padding that matches the video's aspect ratio. To get the padding/aspect ratio, divide the video's height by the width and multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

#video {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}

#video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zWAiQJvwb8Q?  autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&playlist=zWAiQJvwb8Q&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: HERO OF MY DAY 

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap 4 classes `embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9` along with this css hack did it for me.

```
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9 iframe {
    clip-path: inset(1px 1px);
}
```

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26284#issuecomment-392017929

Comment: in which div I should give `embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9` class?

Comment: The parent div. This fixed it for me when nothing else was working. Thanks!