# youtube video screen black bars scenario

Tags: html, css, youtube

How do you make a youtube video full-screen width and height but make the video full size and it completely fills up the entire screen even when you resize but I don't want this to have the black bars at all when resizing.

CSS

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px; height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.video-container .video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video">
        <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EgPRLAJB13c?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out on CodePen for viewport resizing to see the responsiveness. 
 https://codepen.io/rickydam/pen/dzyEoR/left/

Refer to this similar question. 
[Responsive fullscreen youtube video with no black bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617154/responsive-fullscreen-youtube-video-with-no-black-bars)

This article sums up embedding a responsive Youtube video using CSS. 
https://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 0px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
 
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EgPRLAJB13c?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```